# Passing NSTimer has parameter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unit-testing, ocunit

I have method which take `NSTimer` has parameter which is in Class A

```
-(void)demoMethod:(NSTimer *)timer{
    //Do something!
}
```

Now I have covering test case for the method:

```
-(void)testDemoMethodPassNilTimer{

    //Created class Instance for the ClassA

    ClassA *testA = [[ClassA alloc]init];

    //[test testDemoMethod:nil];

    STAssertThrows([testA testDemoMethod:nil],@"should throw exception");

}

-(void)testDemoMethodPassTimer{

    ClassA *testA = [[ClassA alloc]init];
    STAssertNoThrows([testA testDemoMethod:??????]);
}
```

What should be the proper way to pass the parameter for `NSTimer` Object for the test Case method `testDemoMethodPassTimer`?

Comment: Do you want to pass parameter to NSTimer to access in demoMethod: method?

Answer (score 0):

Give it an actual timer object, but don't schedule it on the run loop.

Answer (score 0):

It was also my need to parse parameter to NSTimer. So I had come up with creation of category class, which helped me.

**Here are the steps to create Category class over NSTimer.**

1. Right click on project and select "New File"
2. Cacoa Touch > Objective-C category > Next
3. Give Category : additions & Category on : NSTimer
4. in .h file just create property of placeId
5. in .m synthesize it using @dynamic & create setter, getter
6. import that .h file in you file.

**NSTimer+additions.h file**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSTimer (additions)

     @property(nonatomic,retain)    NSString  *additionalTag;

@end
```

**NSTimer+additions.m file**

```
#import "NSTimer+additions.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

NSString *const additionalTagKey = @"additionalTagKey";

@implementation NSTimer (additions)
@dynamic additionalTag;

- (void)setAdditionalTag:(NSString*)aObject
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, additionalTagKey, aObject, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
- (NSString*)additionalTag
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, additionalTagKey);
}

@end
```

**Now `#import "NSTimer+additions.h"` in your class using NSTimer**

**Passing parameter to NSTimer**

```
-(void)testDemoMethodPassTimer{

    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                              target:self
                              selector:@selector(timerTick:)
                              userInfo:nil
                              repeats:YES];
    timer.additionalTag = @"parameter passed to timer";

    ClassA *testA = [[ClassA alloc]init];
    STAssertNoThrows([testA testDemoMethod:timer]);
}
```

**Retrieving parameter from timer**

```
-(void)demoMethod:(NSTimer *)timer{
    NSLog(@"My Parameter: %@",timer.additionalTag);
}
```

Many Steps are involved but hopefully help you a bit. :)